# Cuando inserto datos en una tabla de SQLite, dice que la base de datos esta bloqueada

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, sqlite, wpf

Estoy creando una aplición en `WPF` el cual inserta en una tabla de `SQLite` cada inicio de sesión.

Cuando esta a punto de insertar: tira esta excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo del método para insertar es este:

```
public void InsertValuesToDataBase (string user, string pass)
    {
        if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "DB.sqlite"))
        {
            SQLiteConnection conectionInsert = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "DB.sqlite;" + "Version=3;");

            string consulta = "INSERT INTO User (user, pass) values(@param1,@param2)";

            SQLiteCommand Insert = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conectionInsert);

            Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", user);
            Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", pass);

            conectionInsert.Open();
            Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectionInsert.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            //alter here
        }
    }
```

Y lo llamo desde otra clase de esta manera:

```
sim_sql_lite = new SIMSQLite();
sim_sql_lite.InsertValuesToDataBase("abc", "123");
```

La ubicación del archivo de `SQLite` esta en el mismo directorio donde `Visual Studio` crea el compilado `.exe` del programa.

```
C:\...\bin\Debug
```

¿Algúna sugerencia?

Comment: Te falla la primera vez que insertas? La segunda? Siempre?

Comment: Siempre que intento insertar.

Comment: Lo mas probable es que antes de este código estes leyendo algo de la base de datos (un reader a lo mejor) y no estes correctamente liberando sus recursos. Siempre es bueno usar clausulas `using` para que se ejecute el dispose de los objetos que implementan Idisposable

Comment: @Pikoh concuerdo en parte  ya que es recomendable usar un `using ` pero no veo un reader en el código que comparte.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza ni yo. Pero es que el código que muestra no es todo su código. Por eso conjeturo que el problema es que está dejando alguna conexion abierta anteriormente a llamar a este código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez se ha quedado estancado el gestor de **Sqlite Open Helper**, una vez me paso que este gestor se habia quedado trabado y me habia bloqueado la base de datos. Intenta reiniciar el gestor. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer falta el campo de Password en la cadena de conexión.

```
public void InsertValuesToDataBase (string user, string pass)
{
    if (File.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "DB.sqlite"))
    {
        SQLiteConnection conectionInsert = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "DB.sqlite;" + "Version=3; Password=012345679;");

        string consulta = "INSERT INTO User (user, pass) values(@param1,@param2)";

        SQLiteCommand Insert = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conectionInsert);

        Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", user);
        Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", pass);

        conectionInsert.Open();
        Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conectionInsert.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        //alter here
    }
}
```